# Moviepy slidein and slideout transitions

Tags: python, effects, moviepy

I'm trying to use slide in and out transitions between videoclips with no luck I was only available to make it work using crossfadein like this:

```
 from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips, vfx, afx, transfx, concatenate, 
 CompositeVideoClip

 delay = 1
 output = "out.mp4"
 clip1 = VideoFileClip("174_3.mp4")
 clip2 = VideoFileClip("174_4.mp4")
 clip3 = VideoFileClip("174_5.mp4")
 clip4 = VideoFileClip("174_6.mp4")


final = concatenate([clip1,
                 clip2.crossfadein(delay),
                 clip3.crossfadein(delay),
                 clip4.crossfadein(delay)],
         padding=-delay, method="compose")
final.write_videofile(output)
```

But when I use the example on  https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/3d86a2c4cba6769528112765d964eaec273d7636/moviepy/video/compositing/transitions.py

```
 from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips, vfx, afx, transfx, concatenate, 
 CompositeVideoClip

 output = "out.mp4"
 clip1 = VideoFileClip("174_3.mp4")
 clip2 = VideoFileClip("174_4.mp4")
 clip3 = VideoFileClip("174_5.mp4")
 clip4 = VideoFileClip("174_6.mp4")

 clips = [clip1, clip2, clip3, clip4];
 CompositeVideoClip(clips)

 slided_clips = [clip.fx( transfx.slide_out, 1, 'bottom') for clip in clips]
 final_clip = concatenate( slided_clips, padding=-1)
 final_clip.write_videofile(output)
```

This result is videos concatenated but not transition at all, please let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Just wondering, does calling `CompositeVideoClip(clips)` actually modify `clips`? Might you need to do `clips = CompositeVideoClips(clips)` instead?  I’m not sure...

Comment: yes actually that does nothing it was one of the many test I did, if I use clips = CompositeVideoClips(clips) it just  throws an error on the for cicle

Comment: definitely must keep return values (`clips = CompositeVideoClips([c1,c2,...])`; the functions to not modify the original video, but rather take effect when the final output is rendered. See [composite video](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html#compositevideoclips) and also: ["All these effects have in common that they are not inplace: they do NOT modify the original clip"](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/effects.html). Still, I have the same issue. Also found bug for this issue: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/649

Answer (score 3):

Remember that most functions in moviepy do not modify the object, but return a modified shallow copy of the object - so the line `CompositeVideoclip(clips)` does not do anything.

Instead, you want to do:

`slided_clips = [CompositeVideoClip([clip.fx( transfx.slide_out, 1, 'bottom')]) for clip in clips]`

The reason why `slide_out` has to be in CompositeVideoClip is because it changes the position of the clip, so it needs to be in a "frame" to leave part of the screen blank. It's the same reason why `set_position` works only with CompositeVideoClip.

Comment: Does the transition actually work after this correction, though? When I try it, the videos are concatenated, but with a simple cut transition, rather than any type of slide effect.

Comment: Well, if you used slide_in, it would work. Slide_out is broken in the current release - see https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/753